# Multiplying input values

Tags: javascript

I am currently attempting a challenge question in one of my homeworks. For now I have written a code that adds all input values until [0] is inputted. The code goes like this:

```
do {
              results = scanner.nextInt();
              value += results;
} while (results != 0);
```

However, after attempting to write a code for multiplication, I keep getting my output as 0. I realized that one of the issues was due to the fact that I had previously set my variable `value` to ```= 0````. Therefore, I created a new variable with a set value of equal to 1. Because any number multiplied to one, is just that number.
With many attempts I wrote this code:

```
 int product = 1;
                        do {
                            results = scanner.nextInt();
                            product *= results;
                        } while (results != 0);
```

I don' understand why this code is not working. My am multiplying `1` to the values inputted into the loop, so I don't get how the output is zero.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

When you input zero, `results` is set to `0` and multiplied with `product` before you leave the do-while loop.

Just add a check where multiplication does not occur if `result = 0`

Here is one way to do it

```
int product = 1;

while (1){
    result = scanner.nextInt();
    if(result == 0){
        break;
    }
    product *= result;
}
// print product here
```

Answer (score 0):

You multiply by result until result is zero. Any number * zero = zero. When result is 0 I should not multiply by it.